# Previous siblings selectors for jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

If I have a simple HTML list

```
<ul>
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li id="some-id">Item 3</li>
  <li>Item 4</li>
  <li>Item 5</li>
</ul>
```

it's easy to select every list item *after* `#some-id`:

```
$("#some-id ~ li")
```

but how do I select the items *before* `#some-id`?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use [`.prevAll()`](http://api.jquery.com/prevAll/), like this:

```
$("#some-id").prevAll()
```

For example:

```
$("#some-id").prevAll().css('color', 'red')​​​​​​​​​​​;​
```

[Give it a try here](http://jsfiddle.net/q6Nd4/), there's not a "previous siblings" selector like your [next-siblings selector](http://api.jquery.com/next-siblings-selector/), but [`.prevAll()`](http://api.jquery.com/prevAll/) will get the elements you want, the same as you could substitute your current selector with [`$("#some-id").nextAll()`](http://api.jquery.com/nextAll/).

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#some-id").prevAll()
```

See the documentation: http://api.jquery.com/prevAll/