# jQuery filter and html return strange result

Tags: javascript, jquery

Why the following code not work as expected? (Select all elements before the div with class = clear?)

**HTML:**

```
<div id="text">    
    line0
    <div>line1</div>
    <div>line2</div>

    <div class="clear" />        
    <div>dummy</div>
    <p>dummy</p>        
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
var allow = true;    
var output = $('#text *').filter(function(index) {        
    if( $(this).attr("class") == 'clear') {
        allow = false;
    }

    return allow;        
}).html().trim();

alert( output );
```

**​Output:**

```
line1
```

**Expect:**
    line0
    line1
    line2

Comment: NITPICK: `$(this).attr("class") == 'clear'` is bad since if you add another class to it at some point it will break. use [`hasClass`](http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/).

Comment: @epascarello. LOL, just wrote that... `:)`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Previous siblings selectors for jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3228101/previous-siblings-selectors-for-jquery)

Comment: @epascarello, I have updated my code, it is not a duplicate as prevAll does not work in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens because as the [`.html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) says

> Get the HTML contents of the first element in the set of matched
>   elements.

So though both of your div is selected only one is returned by `.html()`

Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/joycse06/uRK7Y/1/) to verify you code is returning both elements.

And as other have already said you should use the `.hasClass` method.

**UPDATE**

As that `line0` is not inside any node, its a textNode, You can loop and add span tags around textNodes first. Or you wont be able to apply styling to that text. Check the following code

```
var whitespace = /^\s*$/;
$('#text').contents().filter(function(){
    return this.nodeType == 3 && !whitespace.test(this.nodeValue);
}).wrap('<span></span>');
```

This loops through all childNodes(including textnodes) and wrap non-space textnodes with `span`.

So after that your line0 will be inside a span tag like `<span>line0</span>`. So now if you do

```
$('.clear').prevAll().css('color', 'red');
```

It will highlight `line0` too.

Check [Node Types](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/nodeType) Doc on MDN

[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/joycse06/GHX3B/1)

Comment: Thanks, pls see my updated example: http://jsfiddle.net/gWCdL/, I also want line0 to be highlighted

Comment: Maybe I am not clean, what my target is in fact: 1. Remove all nodes after the last clear, 2. html() the remaining dom tree. I have put up a example here: http://jsfiddle.net/vsekN/, actually it works, but not sure why there is a additional DIV at the last line. Thanks abyway

Answer (score 2):

Because the html() method returns the contents of the first element in the selector.

http://api.jquery.com/html/

> If the selector expression matches more than one element, only the first match will have its HTML content returned.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.clear').prevAll().css('color', 'red').fadeOut(2000);​
```

[**Live DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/faQyt/1)

And by the way, if you want to check if an element has a class use `.hasClass(class)`
**Example:**

```
var hasClass = $(this).hasClass('clear');
```

Comment: I have think of prevall, but the problem is it failed in this case: http://jsfiddle.net/gWCdL/ (I want line0 also seleceted and fadeout)